# PowerShell script to ask registry for exists key and true/false output

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

How can I write script to asking registry if **RebootRequired** exits in next path? **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired**
and if **RebootRequired** exists output> true
and if **RebootRequired** not exists output> false

I tried several attempts without success

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Test-Path -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired"}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution; please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777) so that it becomes more readable. Note that you don't need `Invoke-Command` just to call `Test-Path`. Since you're passing a _literal_ registry path (no wildcards), it is conceptually clearer to use the `-LiteralPath` parameter: `$isRebootPending = Test-Path -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired'`